# using runST for Fibonacci issues

Tags: haskell, mutable

I have defined the following

```
import Data.STRef

fib' :: Int -> Integer
fib' n = runST $ do
                 rx <- newSTRef 0
                 ry <- newSTRef 1
                 let loop 0 = do
                            x <- readSTRef rx
                            return x
                     loop n = do
                            x <- readSTRef rx
                            y <- readSTRef ry
                            writeSTRef rx y
                            writeSTRef ry (x + y)
                            loop (n - 1)
                 loop n
```

However when I attempt to compile the code using ghci I get the following error:

```
    Variable not in scope: runST :: GHC.ST.ST s0 Integer -> Integer
   |
11 | fib' n = runST $ do
   |          ^^^^^
```

I don't know where I've gone wrong, I am quite new to using mutable references in haskell so any help would be appreciated

Comment: you did not import `runST`.

Comment: "*I am quite new to using mutable references in haskell*": mutuable references are seldomly used.

Comment: How do I import it? I thought I did it with import Data.STRef

Comment: No, you can for example import it with `import Control.Monad.ST(runST)`.

Comment: Yes that fixed it thank you

Comment: Using `STRef`s for this purpose is sure to produce considerably less efficient code than you'd get doing it purely. If you want to go fast, use exponentiation by squaring with matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is to add

```
import Control.Monad.ST(runST)
```

as this module is required